# Crawl and extract websites to certain format

Tags: web-crawler

I need a crawler to fetch webpages and extract certain data from them .
I've done this thing in php but it's pretty buggy I was asking if there's an open source platform or anything that can do it .

**Explain ?**

the fetched page content

```
iPhone 5S is a great phone with 1.2 Ghz dual core processor .
```

The crawler should return

```
iPhone > product name (given in a database )

1.2 Ghz > processor (the code should be able to identify the ghz or MHz to understand that this is a processor value )

Dual core > processor cores
```

This is a simple example of what it should do , it should be able to identify things inside contexts and ignore unneeded strings and numbers .

Is there is anything like that ??

Comment: This is an interesting question, yet it is not a very good fit for SO. It is not well defined enough. It seems to fall into both into the "tool recommendation" category and into "many possible answers or good answers may be too long". There is a very powerful commercial tool called Lixto and it has many clones. Also many open source tools, such as Scrapy. Lack of direct links is intentional.